# Can someone explain to me how ActionView templates work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not asking how to use them, I'm asking how do they work. My controller (just used one of the scaffold generators for my controller) has a method:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

From that method, I can either get the html response (index.html.erb), even without specifying "html" in the request, or I can get a json response (index.json.jbuilder).

In other methods there's `format.html` and `format.json`. In the above example method `index`, there's no reference to either "type" of response. Why/how does it work?!?

**Request for /users** -- expected default html

**Request for /users.html** -- expected html response

**Request for /users.js** -- I get back the html content of `<body>` (maybe that's the partial?)

I do not have a template specified for .js anywhere.

**Request for /users.txt** -- I get the expected error message:

```
Missing template users/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
```

**Request for /users.xml** -- I get the expected error message, even though xml seems more practical than a .js handler of a main resource:

```
Missing template users/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xml], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}
```

Why is a request for .abc even being processed at all? Even though it's not indicating that it's html, that's how it's processing it.

```
Started GET "/users.abc" ...
Processing by UsersController#index as
```

I see that there are :handlers specified, but none specify how/what should be handling the .js request. Why isn't the .js request spitting out an error? Hell, how is this all working without a respond_to block? I guess I expect the html handler by default, but I do not expect the .json response by default. There are often cases where I'd like all kinds of formats to be able to be returned, sometimes I'd prefer only to have a .json response over an html one. How/where do I find the documentation for dealing with this? It's not really related to the respond_to block, since even in the absence of respond_to, I'm getting multi format output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a controller, when no mime types are defined, rails will simply render the default one:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

is equivalent to

```
respond_to :html

def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_with @users
end
```

This being said, let's take a look at other mime types:

**Request for /users.js**

This one is interesting, looking at the rails code base [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0.rc2/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb#L167-L169) we can see that it will render a template using `default_render`:

```
# to_js simply tries to render a template. If no template is found, raises the error.
def to_js
  default_render
end
```

This is the default case for the `html` mime type also:

```
# HTML format does not render the resource, it always attempt to render a
# template.
#
def to_html
  default_render
rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate => e
  # ...
end
```

**One does it means ?** -- If a js template is defined, rails will render it. Otherwise, it will fallback to render the default html template. This is why you get the html content of `<body>`. Look your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file:

```
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

**Request for /users.txt** and **Request for /users.xml**

Basically all "undefined by default" mime types will require you define some logic to not throw an exception. From rails source:

```
def respond
  method = "to_#{format}"
  respond_to?(method) ? send(method) : to_format
end
```

Rails define by default `to_html` and `to_js`. For other mime types, you will need to satisfy the conditions of the [following method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0.rc2/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb#L175-L183). For `json` and `xml`, it simply means calling `to_json`, `to_xml` or using `respond_to`.

For more information, take a look at the `responder.rb` file in rails source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0.rc2/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb). It's always good to look at rails source to really understand how things work. Of course sometimes it requires to spare some time and jumping around methods and files.

Comment: How is a request for *.xyz handled then? I'm getting a valid response (html).

Comment: Simply following the flow, you end up in the 'to_format' method where the default_render apply since the conditions are met and that you did not provide a 'to_xyz' method.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this default behaviour? I'd rather have to explicitly allow a particular response, rather than *all*.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what would be the reaction of rails if a controller's method get request of, let's say, JS format while there's no "reposnd_to" block, but I think that it'd answer with error "unacceptible format". So I think that by default it assumes that request is of html format and to answer for other than html you have to point out with respond_to format block.

What about how the mechanism work, "rails determines the desired response format from the HTTP Accept header submitted by the client" (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb#L85) rails sources says. So accepted formats is stated explicitly while generating request in mime-type

Comment: That's not the case at all. Using my example method `index`, exactly as is -- I get an html and a json response.

Comment: @jacobsd wowowow, man don't be hasty: the fact you pointed out means only that my guess about controller's inability to automatically respond was wrong. But your question was about mechanism of format determination: so my answer for this is the same: it contained in Accept header of request. Look into rails log after any request

Comment: I do appreciate the attention (and the response), but it still doesn't answer the question that I asked. Even without a respond_to block my index method is serving both a .json and an .html request (that I know of). As an example... I chose to do a request for /users.js -- I got back what appears to be the html body (no <html>, <head>, or <body>. Just the content of "<body>". I'd obviously like to limit/prevent this kind of behaviour and I'm sure there is a way.